# Distributing events across different JVMs with Axon Server to Subscribing Event Processors (without Event Sourcing)

Tags: cqrs, distributed-system, event-driven, axon

I'm using Axon Framework (4.1) with aggregates in one module (JVM, container) and projections/Sagas in another module. What I want to do is to have a distributed application taking advantage of CQRS **but without Event Sourcing**.

It is rather trivial to setup and everything works as expected in a single application. The problem arises when there are several independent modules (across separate JVMs) involved. Out of the box Axon starter uses tracking processors connected to `AxonServerEventStore`, which allows to have "location transparency" when it comes to listening to the events across different JVMs.

In my case, I don't want any infrastructure for persisting or tracking the events. I just want to distribute the events to any subscribing processors (SEPs) from my aggregates in **a fire-and-forget style**, just like `AxonServerQueryBus` is doing to distribute scatter-gather queries, for example.

If I just declare all processors as subscribing as follows:

```java
    @Autowired
    public void configureEventSubscribers(EventProcessingConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.usingSubscribingEventProcessors();
    }
```

events are reaching all `@EventHandler` methods in the same JVM, but events are not reaching any handlers in other JVMs anymore. If my understanding is correct, then, Axon Server will distribute the events across JVMs for *tracking processors only* (TEPs).

Obviously, what I can do, is to use an external message broker (RabbitMQ, Kafka) in combination with `SpringAMQPMessageSource` (as in the docs) to distribute events to all subscribers through something like fanout in RabbitMQ. This works, but this requires to maintain the broker myself.

What would be nice is to have Axon Server taking care of this just like it takes care of distributing commands and queries (this would give me one less infrastructure piece to care about).

As a side note, I've actually managed to distribute the events to projections using `QueryBus` and passing events as payloads to `GenericQueryMessage` sent as scatter-gather queries. Needless to say, this is not a robust solution. But it goes to demonstrate that there is nothing inherently impossible with Axon Server distributing events (just another type of a message, after all) to SEPs or TEPs indifferently.

Finally, the questions:

1) What is the community's recommendation for pure CQRS (without Event Sourcing) using Axon when it comes to location transparency and distributing the events?

2) Is it possible to make Axon Server to distribute events to SEPs across JVMs (eliminating the need for an external message broker)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note on Event Sourcing**

From Axon Framework's perspective, Event Sourcing is a sole concern of your Command Model. This stance is taken, as Event Sourcing defines the recreation of a model through the events *it* has published. A Query Model however does not react to commands with publishing events changing its state, it simply listen to (distributed) events to update its state to be queried by others.
As such, the framework only thinks about Event Sourcing when it recreates your Aggregates, by providing the `EventSourcingRepository`.

The Event Processor's job is to be the "mechanical aspect of providing events to your Event Handlers". This relates to the Q part in CQRS, to recreating the Query Model.
Thus, the Framework does not regard Event Processors to be part of the notion of Event Sourcing.

**Answer to your scenario**

I do want to emphasize that if you are distributing your application by running *several* instances of a given app, you will very likely need to have a way to ensure a given event is only handled **once**.

This is one of the concerns a Tracking Event Processor (TEP) addresses, and it does so by using a Tracking Token.
The Tracking Token essential acts as a marker defining which events have been processed. Added, a given TEP's thread is inclined to have a claim on a token to be able to work, which thus ensure a given event is not handled twice.

Concluding, you will need to define infrastructure to store Tracking Tokens to be able to distributed the event load, essentially opting against the use of the `SubscribingEventProcessor` entirely.

However, whether the above is an issu does depend on your application landscape.
Maybe you aren't duplicating a given application at all, thus effectively **not** duplicating a given Tracking Event Processor.
In this case, you can fulfill your request to "not track events", whilst still using Tracking Event Processors.
All you have to do, is to ensure you are not storing them. The interface used to storing tokens, is the `TokenStore`, for which an *in memory* version exists.

Using the `InMemoryTokenStore` in a default Axon set up will however mean you'll technically be replaying your events every time. This occurs due to the default "initial Tracking Token" process. This is, of course, also configurable, for which I'd suggest you to use the following approach:

```
// Creating the configuration for a TEP
TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration tepConfig = 
    TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration
        .forSingleThreadedProcessing() // Note: could also be multi-threaded
        .andInitialTrackingToken(StreamableMessageSource::createHeadToken);

// Registering as default TEP config
EventProcessingConfigurer.
    registerTrackingEventProcessorConfiguration(config -> tepConfig);
```

This should set you up to use TEP, without the necessity to set up infrastructure to store Tokens. Note however, this will require you **not** to duplicate the given application.

---

I'd like to end with the following question you've posted:

> Is it possible to make Axon Server to distribute events to SEPs across JVMs (eliminating the need for an external message broker)?

As you have correctly noted, SEPs are (currently) only usable for subscribing to events which have been published within a given JVM. Axon Server does not (yet) have a mechanism to bridge events from one JVM to another for the purpose allowing distributed Subscribing Event Processing. I am (as part of AxonIQ) however relatively sure we will look in to this in the future. If such a feature is of importance to successful conclusion of your project, I suggest to [contact](https://axoniq.io/#getInContact) AxonIQ directly.

Comment: Steven, thanks for the thorough and helpful answer. It clarified quite a bit for me the use of tracking in Axon. When I was thinking about separating aggregates and projections into different services (like Docker Swarm _services_) my reasoning was to have aggregates as a central point of all business logic processing (driven by commands from the _write_ side of CQRS) and the N number of different projections driving _read-only_ representations (of the aggregates' state) one for each business context. This is pretty much strait-forward CQRS.

Comment: What I did not think about was that in a Docker service we can have several instances (replicas) of _the same application_ (aggregates or projections) active at the same time (scaling up). So, of course, each instance will be notified of the same event, so we need to track which events have already been processed by the replicas of each service (just what you were saying).

Comment: I am experimenting with RabbitMQ as an external message broker with one topic and each service declaring a separate queue for _each subscribing processor_ (aggregates, Sagas, projections, query handlers) connected to this common topic. This way every service will be notified of every event (pub-sub), but since the replicas in each service share the same queue, only one will process each particular event at any given time thus eliminating the need for tracking of the events.

Comment: The final idea is to have Axon taking care of commands and queries and to get rid of event sourcing altogether (no event store, no token stores, no TEPs, only SEPs and a `SimpleEventBus` in each service).  After all, CQRS and ES are "orthogonal concepts", and I think Axon in an excellent way to go about _pure CQRS_.

Comment: Happy to have been of help @George! Related to your last comment, I want to point out that Axon Server is usable as just a messaging solution. You can thus opt out of storing events if that's what you'd require. However, like I pointed out in my answer above, this for the moment does not include the use of a Subscribing Event Processor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Apache Kafka for this use case, you might want to look into kalium.alkal.io. 
It will make your code to be much simpler

```
MyObject myObject = ....
kalium.post(myObject); //this is used to send POJOs/protobuffs using Kafka Producer
```

```
//On the consumer side. This will use a deserializer with the Kafka Consumer API
kalium.on(MyObject.class, myObject -> {
   // do something with the object
}, "consumer_group");
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Kalium looks like an interesting project...